# Duplicate content: Prevent testing and development site from getting crawled and indexed

Tags: seo, google-search-console, duplicate-content, canonical-url, rel-canonical

I am running a WordPress based site on **example.com** with its original content.

I then have another site running on **example.me** which is basically the exact copy of the original **example.com** together with all example.com's content and I'm using this **example.me** only for testing purposes, to develop and test new plugins and functionality which I then deploy on the main domain **example.com**.

I use the default WordPress settings on **example.me** that disables robots from crawling the site, but WordPress warns that this may not always work.

Is there any other way to let Google know straight away that this site **example.me** is a duplicate of **example.com** and is not be indexed?

Some kind of general canonical tag that I could use for the entire site?

Is there maybe a setting in webmaster tools to have this done?

Comment: No canonical link for an entire site exists. Instead, block it using robots.txt or by putting noindex in your template so that it appear on each page. The easiest way is to use robots.txt. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Canonical tags are not designed to work domain wide, they are designed to identify the canonical link on a page by page basis. The best way is to use a robots.txt file containing the following...

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

What this robots.txt file is telling the crawlers is not to crawl or index the site at all. Now whether or not a crawler respects this file is up to them and so can't be used to prevent robots access for security reasons however for the purpose you've mentioned given the site is full of duplicate content and is designed as a development and testing environment it will work and prevent the site from being indexed and crawled by Google for indexing reasons.